# Is this logic proof valid?

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

I need to prove that (a → (¬a → b)) is a tautology using only these axioms: [image: these axioms], Modus Ponens (MP), and Deduction.

Here is the work I have done:

[image: Here is the the work I have done.]

The problem is that it doesn't seem right to suppose "a" is true and then suppose "not a" is true at the same time. I asked my classmates and they did the same in their proofs. Is it really possible to assume two things that contradict each other in deduction? If not, what is the correct way to go about this proof?

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: And the "meaning" of logical law $\lnot \alpha \to (\alpha \to \beta)$ is exactly that : it is not possible that $\alpha$ and $\lnot \alpha$ are both true because, if so, "everything is true", and this is not what we want.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm still a bit confused; how do we know that $\lnot \alpha \to (\alpha \to \beta)$ only follows from the contradictory premise $\alpha, \neg \alpha$ and wouldn't follow from a non-contradictory premise?

Comment: Not clear... we have proved it (your proof above works) according to the rules of the calculus.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the confirmation. It's just strange to me that two lines within the proof are contradictory since I was under the impression every line must be true or a premise.

Comment: Correct; "true (i.e. already proved) or *premises*". They are premises in the proof, that amounts to $\lnot \alpha, \alpha \vdash \beta$. Then the result follows by two applications of Deduction Th.

Comment: See [Ex falso quodlibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion#Symbolic_representation). The principle is considered "counterintuitive" by some logicians (old and new).